# Parallel computing doesn't use my own settings

Tags: parallelization, system

To differentiate the conjugate of a function,
I used such settings.

```
excluded = 
  "ExcludedFunctions" /.
   ("DifferentiationOptions" /. 
     SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"]);
SetSystemOptions[
  "DifferentiationOptions" -> 
   "ExcludedFunctions" -> Union[excluded, {Conjugate}]];
```

```
Unprotect[Conjugate];
Conjugate /: D[Conjugate[f__], x__] := Conjugate[D[f, x]]
Protect[Conjugate];
```

And I got some values of the derivative of a function,
both with `Table` and `ParallelTable`.

```
Table[dF1[n] /. n -> i // N // Chop, {i, -1, +1}]
ParallelTable[dF1[n] /. n -> i // N // Chop, {i, -1, +1}]
```

The results are :

```
{0.738633, 0, -0.738633}
{-0.690983 ((-0.53448 + 4.72022 I) - (3.50458 + 3.20688 I) Derivative[
     1][Conjugate][0.386187 + 0.757935 I]), ...}
```

I recognized that the parallel computation doesn't inherit the settings I have done.

How can I use such settings on parallel computation?

Comment: Have you seen [`DistributeDefinitions`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/DistributeDefinitions.html) ? If the modified version can not be distributed, them probably you will need to change the definition in all kernels using [`ParallelEvaluate`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/ParallelEvaluate.html) and your code `Unprotect[Conjugate];Conjugate /: ...`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll try them.

Comment: That `ParallelEvaluate` perfectly removed the problem! Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want, you could write an answer yourself, so that could help other users and you can get lot more site reputation. Remember to say if  `DistributeDefinitions` was a solution too, or not.

Answer (score 2):

rherman's comment resolved my problem.

I added `DistributeDefinitions[excluded]` after the first line of code,
though the given result was not different.
I think I misused it..

But when I covered all arguments with `ParallelEvaluate`,
all kernels acted correctly as I expected.

Here is the code :

```
excluded = "ExcludedFunctions" /.
   ("DifferentiationOptions" /. SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"]);
ParallelEvaluate[SetSystemOptions[
   "DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions" -> Union[excluded, {Conjugate}]]];
```

```
ParallelEvaluate[Unprotect[Conjugate]];
ParallelEvaluate[
  Conjugate /: D[Conjugate[f__], x__] := Conjugate[D[f, x]]];
ParallelEvaluate[Protect[Conjugate]];
```

Comment: Did you try `DistributeDefinitions[Conjugate]` on a fresh kernel?

Comment: Sorry for forgetting the comment. I think I misused it, but such method didn't work well.